# Detecting "no more moves" in a puzzle game

Tags: c#, xna, puzzle

I wrote a small game a while back in Flash that I'm now re-coding in C# with my new programming experience. However this time around, I want to be able to implement the idea of detecting when the grid has become impossible to solve. This is more of a conceptual puzzle problem then anything, but I'll take any resources you may have.

The game involves moving the player up, down, left, or right around the map, pushing blocks around. The level is won when there are no more blocks of certain kinds left. However it's easy to find yourself in a no longer solvable map. For example if the player starts off stuck in a ring of wall blocks, then there's no way to solve it at all.

Sorry for the abstract question, but does anybody have any tips for this?

Comment: I don't get the down votes or close votes. This is a perfectly valid question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically have two options. Both have advantages and disadvantages, so you might want to combine ideas from both into your solution.

**Option 1: Write a heuristic**

Think about situations which make the game impossible to solve (such as being stuck in a ring of wall blocks). Detect such situations and print "no more moves" as soon as such a situation occurs. The more such situations you can think of and implement, the better your algorithm becomes.

Advantage: Easy and fast.

Disadvantage: There will be cases where the game is unsolvable but your algorithm does not detect it.

**Option 2: Write a solver**

Write a program that, given a *state* of your game (where is the player, where are the blocks, etc.), outputs a list of steps that can be taken to solve the game (or `null` or some other special value when there is no solution anymore -- this is your "no more moves" case).

How to implement something like this depends on the exact rules of the game. A simple approach is to do a [Breadth-First Search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) on the [Game Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_tree): Every node in your tree is a game state, and every arc between nodes is a possible action that the player could take (move up, move down, etc.).

Advantage: This reliably detects when the game cannot be won anymore. In addition, this program can be used to give hints to the player when he gets stuck.

Disadvantage: Depending on the complexity of your game, calculating a solution might take ages. For very simple games this could work; for somewhat simple games it might take very long, and for fairly complex games such a chess or checkers, it's very hard or impossible.

Comment: The heuristic method would probably be the best situation given the complexity of the game. Thanks for the tips!

Answer (score 0):

There's always the brute-force way for just about any situation - just create the entire tree of moves the player could make. If none of them leads to a win, the game is impossible to win.

Of course, for games like solitaire, you should only take into account what the user knows, not any hidden elements in the game - some solitaire games are just impossible to begin with, but the player shouldn't know that. For other, more complex games, brute-force is not suitable because the tree takes too long to generate. In these cases, you'll need to find common patterns and detect those.

Sorry, it's a little too vague for any specific answer. But those are my tips.

Answer (score 0):

You received answers on finding if a game is solvable, however, seems to me you're only looking to see if there are any legal moves left, which is a lot easier.

Of course, with no description of the game, it's impossible to give you any concrete advice, but just take @Heinzi's advice and remember you're only looking to see if there are any legal moves. So if you can actually build a non-empty [Game Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_tree), there are some legal moves left.

Answer (score 0):

I needed something similar one time. I did a random generated maze and needed to know if it possible to solve it...

I did a test that tested all possible solutions. The game area (2D) was 10*14 tiles big and the player could move in 4 directions (like in your game). My game was just about going from point A to point B. In one way, your game is about the same, it’s about to move the blocks from point A to B. I would start from the blocks current position and then make an algorithm that try to move it in each direction. If any direction was possible for the block I would add the tile (who i tried to move the block to) to a list containing all not yet tested tiles that needed to be tested...

So basically start with one tile...test the 4 directions...then test the tiles that were possible to move to. So if it was possible to move the block to the right, then you need to test if it is possible to move the block from the tile to the right to any other position. To keep track of what tiles you have tested, ad a variable in the tile that tells if it is tested or not and a list of tiles that "is possible to reach" and not yet tested.